# How to filter NPM commands to a pattern of workspaces (like filter, include, exclude, glob, grep or subdirectory)?

Tags: npm, npm-workspaces

I'd like to organise a large NPM monorepo such that I can run commands on many (but not all) workspaces according to a category or pattern.

This could be by subdirectory, or by a pattern in the workspace names like a prefix or suffix, but I can't see any way to do either in NPM alone.

---

In **Yarn >= 2**, this is possible using `--include` or `--exclude` flags with glob patterns on `yarn workspaces foreach`, for example:

```
yarn workspaces foreach --include "@namespace/plugin-*" --include "@namespace/preset-*" run build
```

...and that builds all your workspaces with that namespace and either the `plugin-` or `preset-` prefix.

---

In **lerna**, the `--scope` flag also took globs allowing patterns, for example:

```
lerna run --scope "@namespace/plugin-*" --scope "@namespace/preset-*" run build
```

---

But in **NPM**, as far I can see in NPM's workspaces documentation [for v7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) and [for v8](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces), it doesn't seem to have the same feature:

- It has a flag `--workspace` which may be used multiple times to create an array but appears to only accept exact workspace names,
- ...and a flag `--workspaces` which appears to run in all workspaces,

...but I can't see any way to either run on all workspaces in a directory or all workspaces matching a pattern. I really don't want to have to list every workspace by name in every script, as there's going to be a lot of them.

Comment: You've found where it would be documented if supported. Looking at the RFC it seems it was explicitly ruled out: https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/accepted/0038-workspaces-run-cmds.md#2-filter-a-subset-of-workspaces.

Comment: See the answer I just posted. Filtering by subdirectory is implemented but undocumented.

Comment: Also... even if there wasn't this direct support for selecting a subdirectory of workspaces, why rule out the possibility that a workaround could be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not documented (at time of asking), but NPM ***can*** filter workspace commands to **subdirectories** of workspaces by giving the `--workspace` flag a path as its value. For example:

```
npm run --workspace packages/presets --workspace packages/plugins build
```

This will find workspaces that are directly in `$project_root/packages/presets/` or `$project_root/packages/plugins/`, but not workspaces in subdirectories of these subdirectories.

Deeper-nested subdirectories can be included using `/**`, like:

```
npm run --workspace packages/** build
```

---

The above examples would work with workspaces organised into subdirectories, defined in package.json like:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/plugins/*",
    "packages/presets/*",
    ...more
  ],
```

...or a catch-all like:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/**",
    ...more
  ],
```

---

While pointing `--workspace` to subdirectories of workspaces instead of individual workspaces like this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere at time of writing, it does appear to be an intentional, planned, supported feature. I found a note proposing it [deep in one of the rfcs](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/117):

> Note: Globs are not supported as a valid --workspace argument value, the proposed alternative is to use npm  --workspace= in which  is a folder containing multiple workspaces.

I couldn't find anything explicitly stating that this proposal was implemented, but I tried reorganising my monorepo into subdirectories and using a subdirectory with the `--workspace` flag, and it worked.

Their reason for choosing paths rather than glob patterns in workspace names (like yarn does and lerna did) appears to be because of the:

> many pitfalls of supporting globs in the variety of supported shells and operational systems

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350662/3404438) is very complete. Just a couple of tweaks that worked for me:

I needed to use the npm command/script before the --workspace flag, and I did not needed to use the `/**` at the end.

```
npm run <script-name> --workspace parent/directory/
```

Examples:

```
npm publish --workspace packages/public/
npm run build --workspace packages/helpers/
```

This is documented in other parts of npm so it took a bit of digging. The information is generally the same in all places, because the `--workspace` flag is a configuration for multiple npm commands:

```
Valid values for the workspace config are either:

Workspace names
Path to a workspace directory
Path to a parent workspace directory (will result in selecting all workspaces within that folder)
```

I found it documented [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#workspace) and [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish#workspace).

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to use globs. Only way to group things would be by parent directory.

Disclaimer: I was going to add a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350662/3404438) but it was becoming too long and details might have been missed. I think that is the right answer.